# Hiding the application main icon in Windows phone 8 once the app installed

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on one application in which I need  app icon is not being displayed in app list after the first activity of application  like log in  gets completed.

Comment: Are you asking about removing application from app list or just changing icon/tile of the app when user registers it/logs in/buys an account? Because I don't think the first option is possible and if it is about the second one, I think you should change your question.

Comment: Remove application icon from app list after launch app for first time.

Comment: I don't think removing the app from app list is possible. It would pose a huge security risk and would go against the basic principles of windows phone security. Thus if you want to find an answer to those questions, you should try forums interested in security related questions and not stack overflow. You porbably won't find any answers related to breaching security or "so called hacking" or virus creating in here, especially if you ask as openly as this without a second thought.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. Imagine how you would remove such app from your phone?